# [robotframework]Why Create a empty element to a list can treat as True, but not applicable to a empty variable

Tags: robotframework, empty-list

Create a empty element to a list, and return True value with "Should Be True" key word.  but not suiteable for create a empty variable.Why is that?
code:

```
${list1}    Create List    ${EMPTY}
${list2}    Set Variable    ${EMPTY}
Should Be True    ${list1}    Create empty list
Should Be True    ${list2}    Set empty variable
```

Log:

20211225 14:24:58.913 :  INFO : ${list1} = ['']

20211225 14:24:58.916 : TRACE : Arguments: [ '' ]

20211225 14:24:58.916 : TRACE : Return: ''

20211225 14:24:58.917 :  INFO : ${list2} =

20211225 14:24:58.918 : TRACE : Arguments: [ [''] | 'Create empty list' ]

20211225 14:24:58.918 : TRACE : Return: None

20211225 14:24:58.919 : TRACE : Arguments: [ '' | 'Set empty variable' ]

20211225 14:24:58.920 :  FAIL : Evaluating expression '' failed: ValueError: Expression cannot be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit counter-intuitive because `${list1}    Create List    ${EMPTY}` is not creating an empty list, but a list with an empty element inside, e.g. `['']`, while `${list2}    Set Variable    ${EMPTY}`  will create an empty variable, e.g. `''`. This is why `Should Be True` passes on the list (list is not empty) but fails on the variable (variable is empty).

Below code exemplifies these cases:

```
    # empty_list == []
    ${empty_list} =     Create List
    log to console      ${empty_list}
    should be empty     ${empty_list}

    # empty_list_1 == ['']
    ${empty_list_1} =    Create List    ${EMPTY}
    log to console       ${empty_list_1}
    should not be empty  ${empty_list_1}

    # empty_var == '' (empty string with length 0)
    ${empty_var} =       Set Variable
    log to console       ${empty_var}
    should be empty      ${empty_var}

    # empty_var_1 == '' (empty string with length 0)
    ${empty_var_1} =     Set Variable    ${EMPTY}
    log to console       ${empty_var_1}
    should be empty      ${empty_var_1}
```

Comment: If all looks good, can you please set is as accepted answer? Thank you!

Comment: Sure, it's done, thanks for your answer